# Alt Tab overlay Win32 identificator

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, alt-tab

I'm mapping events coming from an external sensor (e.g. a keypad) to keyboard shortcuts and I would like to switch applications using the Fast switch overlay window ( i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> menu"), but I want to keep showing the switch menu until an application is chosen.

Basically, what am I doing is this :

```
if(notInSwitchMenu) 
{   // Alt-Tab keystroke, but Alt remains pressed : the menu is still visible
    Press(VK_MENU); 
    Press(VK_TAB); 
    Release(VK_TAB);
}
else
{

    if(event1) //Tab keystroke : next app
    {
        Press(VK_TAB);
        Release(VK_TAB) ;
    } 
    else if(event2) //Shift-Tab keystroke  : previous app
    { 
        Press(VK_SHIFT); 
        Press(VK_TAB);
        Release(VK_TAB);
        Release(VK_SHIFT) 
    }
    else if(event3) // we get out of the menu : the selected app has the focus.
    {
        Release(VK_MENU);
    } 
}
```

The Press and Release simply call SendInput with the right properties.

My problem is that I don't know a robust method to determine if the user is currently in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> program list. **Do anyone know how to identify the Alt-Tab overlay menu with the Win32 API ?**

Comment: Do you know, that using `Ctrl+Alt+Tab` once will force the list to stay opened until you choose an application?

Comment: The `EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART`/`EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND` events tell you when the `Alt`+`Tab` window appears and disappears.

Comment: @Raymond Chen answer that as an answer.

Comment: In your particular case, you know when you press the alt key, just keep a flag in there to knwo when your app is still holding down the alt key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART`/`EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND` events tell you when the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> window appears and disappears.

Comment: To elaborate, use [SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) to receive these events.

Comment: Can anyone attach an example?

Comment: @yonni
as far as I know EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART/EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND does not work correctly since Windows 10. You can try this solution instead
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49597746/511801