# Why a form is needed for a SetWinEventHook callback?

Tags: forms, winapi, hook

Currently, I'm using the powerful SetWinEventHook() function to catch some user-interface's actions like minimizing and maximizing from other window runned by programs on the computer.

So I inspired myself by using the code provided by BrendanMcK on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665579/setting-up-hook-on-windows-messages) and it does work (I mean: the callback function is called when an event occurs) until the line

```
MessageBox.Show("Something")
```

is present. But I don't want to use any form or window for this program..

After [some research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931235/setwineventhook-does-not-catch-any-event), I figured out this kind of hook needs a message loop to allow the redirection of messages from other window handles. Apparently, calling the thread using Application.Run() [should do the trick](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/557342-thread-message-loop-c), but I would prefer something cleaner, in the C# object itself.

So my question is: is it possible to create a message loop inside an object's method?

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/557342-thread-message-loop-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the function doesn't require a window handle so no "form" is needed.  But the MSDN docs for the function is quite explicit:

> The client thread that calls SetWinEventHook must have a message loop in order to receive events.

A message loop is universal in any program that want to receive notifications that are generated externally by other processes or threads.  It is the common solution to the [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).  Clearly any GUI app has a need for such a solution, Windows messages are generated by the operating system.  It isn't different for SetWinEventHook(), the accessibility events originate in other programs.  There is no clean mechanism to "interrupt" a thread and make it run other code, the re-entrancy problems that causes are extremely difficult to deal with.  The thread has to co-operate, it must be idle and ready to receive a notification to safely process it.  A message loop solves that problem.

Pumping a message loop (calling Application.Run) in a method is certainly possible.  But do keep in mind that the method won't return until you explicitly stop the loop with Application.ExitThread.  There is therefore usually only one good place for that call, the Main() method of your program.

Starting your project with a Winforms or WPF project template is a very good way to get this right.  You have no need to actually create a window, call Application.Run() without an argument, after pinvoking SetWinEventHook.