# Why SetWinEventHook do not work with EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void CALLBACK Wineventproc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook,DWORD event,
        HWND hwnd,
        LONG idObject,
        LONG idChild,
        DWORD idEventThread,
        DWORD dwmsEventTime
){
    cout<<"EventId:"<<idEventThread<<endl;
}
int main() {
    CoInitialize(nullptr);
    HWINEVENTHOOK hEventHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART, EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND, nullptr, Wineventproc, 0, 0,
                                               WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);
    if(hEventHook==NULL){
        cout<<"hook fail"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    MSG mess;
    BOOL  bRet;
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
    while ((bRet=GetMessage(&mess, nullptr,0,0))!=0){
        cout<<"2"<<endl;
        if(bRet == -1){
        }else {
            TranslateMessage(&mess);
            DispatchMessage(&mess);
        }
    }
    if(!UnhookWinEvent(hEventHook)){
        return 0;
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Just an easy demo that I want to use `SetWinEventHook()` to get program switch event. But, when I input <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> ([`EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ms697187(v=vs.85))), the `GetMessage()` is still blocked. What's wrong?

Comment: this is because `EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART` sent by csrss, when it handle alt+tab. but if another process register this hot key - no `EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART` event. explorer.exe register alt+tab handler. if during alt+tab message explorer view that it under debugger - it remove hot key. after this again csrss handle this and `EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART` will be

Comment: @RbMm Is that  mean `EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART`  always won't work ?

Comment: in modern systems - in practic yes. the explorer will be handle alt+tab. if want you can test what i say  - attach debugger to explorer. press alt+tab. that you can see that alt+tab select ui is changed to more classic (this is csrss handler) and you code begin work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588438/the-system-events-event-system-switchstart-and-event-system-switchend-works-in-w

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I change to use `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` .