# Is it possible to detect when a window is being activated from Alt+Tab?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to find a way to detect when my `own` window is being activated from `Alt+Tab`.

I thought about using `CBTProc` but `HCB_ACTIVATE` doesn't give this info, also using a `LowLevelKeyboard` hook, but I would like to avoid hooking.

While searching more about I found that there's an API that stores this information [SwitchToThisWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-switchtothiswindow)

> Type: BOOL
>
> A TRUE for this parameter indicates that the window is being switched to using the Alt/Ctl+Tab key sequence. This parameter should be FALSE otherwise.

But this API is used by the `taskbar`, I wonder if is possible to get this information into my window.

Comment: What's wrong with [`WM_ACTIVATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-activate) (Check the __Parameters__ section) _"...Sent to both the window being activated and the window being deactivated. ..."_ ?

Comment: @RichardCritten How does `WM_ACTIVATE` tells me if the window is being activated from alt + tab? `WA_ACTIVE` is also true when you minimize another window that is above your window.

Comment: I don't see how `SwitchToThisWindow` does what you want, `[in] fUnknown` never meant to be output.

Comment: Yes, i misread it

Comment: `WA_ACTIVE` comes close.  But this is a strange requirement, what underlies it?

Comment: Why is activation by `Alt+Tab` important to you ? There are quite a few ways to activate a Window (application) eg `Alt+Esc`, from Task Manager, from Task Bar, minimising other windows until yours becomes active etc ... .  This feels like an XY-Problem.

Answer (score 0):

[`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) can tell you when the user is invoking the <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> switcher, via the `EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART` and `EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND` events:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants

> | Constant/value | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND 0x0015 | The user has released ALT+TAB. This event is sent by the system, never by servers. The `hwnd` parameter of the [`WinEventProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nc-winuser-wineventproc) callback function identifies the window to which the user has switched. If only one application is running when the user presses ALT+TAB, the system sends this event without a corresponding EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART event. |
> | EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART 0x0014 | The user has pressed ALT+TAB, which activates the switch window. This event is sent by the system, never by servers. The `hwnd` parameter of the [WinEventProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nc-winuser-wineventproc) callback function identifies the window to which the user is switching. If only one application is running when the user presses ALT+TAB, the system sends an EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND event without a corresponding EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART event. |

---

**UPDATE**: apparently, these events don't work anymore since Windows 10 onward.  In which case, you have to resort to a dirty hack that correlates events between `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL)` and `SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND)`, eg:

[The system events EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART and EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND works in Windows 7 but not in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588438/)

Comment: This events no more work in latest windows versions. More exactly, when alt+tab handler was inside explorer ( by default) this events not sent. If move handler to csrss ( this possible do if attach debugger to explorer and press alt+tab explorer deregister self hot key handler - it check for debugger during handle alt+tab). Who is handle csrss or explorer visible in ui - pictures from csrss more classic and minimal, compare modern ui from explorer